# Como dizer "so much for" em português?

Tags: tradução-inglês

A expressão *so much for* [indica](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_much_for) desdém, decepção, descaso ou resignação:

> (idiomatic) An expression of dismissiveness, disappointment, disregard, or resignation; something said upon rejecting, giving up on, quitting, or disposing of something.

Um professor meu nos EUA achava que todo o burburinho, toda a falação sobre Teoria de Galois era injustificada: a teoria não era tão interessante, útil ou difícil quanto falavam. Após explicá-la, disse com desdém

> So much for Galois Theory.

Como traduzir para o português?

Comment: Adeus teoria de Galois. Acho que você fechou muito rapido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma possibilidade que expressa o desdém que você descreve é "é só isso", com variações como "não é mais do que isso", "não passa disso", etc.:

> É só isso a Teoria de Galois.
>
> A Teoria de Galois não passa disso.

Outra maneira, mais coloquial, é "taí" (contração de "está aí"), no sentido de "é só nisso que consiste":

> Taí a (tal) Teoria de Galois.

Answer (score 5):

Eu traduziria dessa forma:

```
(e) lá se foi a teoria de Galois
```

Obviamente essa frase teria de vir na conclusão de um texto argumentativo, concluindo dessa forma. Assim como no inglês essa frase certamente não viria isolada.

Comment: Olá Nelson, bem-vindo ao Portuguese SE! Para mim a expressão "e lá se foi" é forte demais para esse caso - ela expressa que a teoria estaria descartada.

Comment: Então... pra mim é isso que quer dizer "so much for". Descartar algo.

Comment: Repare na definição trazida pelo OP:  something said upon rejecting, giving up on, quitting, or disposing of something.

Comment: Aproveito pra perguntar se neste site se usa OP pra se referir ao autor(a) da pergunta.

Comment: Concordo que essa é uma tradução possível da expressão - talvez eu não tenha deixado claro, mas apenas penso que *nesse caso* (da teoria matemática - que não está sendo descartada, mas apenas um tanto esnobada) essa não seria a melhor opção.

Comment: Sobre o OP, há gente há mais tempo no site que talvez possa dizer melhor, mas não vejo com muita frequência; por outro lado, o uso é tão comum nos sites SE que dificilmente se poderia chamar de errado.

Comment: Mas dessa forma nao se estaria traduzindo e sim analisando o mérito do que se está dizendo. Acho que análise de mérito não cabe no caso de tradução. :)

Comment: Não :-) Não estou concordando ou discordando do professor do OP - digo que, conforme a descrição fornecida, ele quer desmitificar, ou reduzir a hype em torno da teoria de Galois, e não descartá-la, como se fosse completamente sem valor ou mesmo errada. Ou seja, só estou tentando levar em conta o contexto - que é sempre determinante em traduções.

Comment: Entendi. Dessa forma tem razão.

Comment: Como falante nativo de inglês, esta resposta é sem dúvida a melhor tanto segundo a definição quanto o contexto descrito pelo OP

Comment: There goes x é x se descarta. É isso mesmo. Lá se foi x. Parabéns.

Answer (score -1):

I would translate to:

> Tanta coisa com a teoria de Galois e afinal…